# Search predecessors only upto a certain node in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I can use the [`predecessors`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.predecessors) function to find all the predecessors of a node. What I want is to find a predecessor upto a certain.

(The graph is constrained to have that one parent)

Example:

[image]

In the above picture, if I call `predecessors` on **node 8**, it would give me `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` as the result (ignoring edges).

I want it to limit the search only upto a certain node. If I want it to limit the search until **4**, it should return only `[4, 5, 6, 7]`. Not anything above it.

Is it possible using native cytoscape functions?

The `predecessors` function accepts selectors and I've tried using that like `node.predecessors("node#4 node")` according to [the docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/compound-nodes). But it returned nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by finding all the successors of the node I'm trying to stop at, then intersecting it with the predecessors of the input node:

```js
const node = cy.$('node#8');
const predecessors = node.predecessors(); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

const requiredRootNode = cy.$('node#4');
const rootChildren = requiredRootNode.successors(); // [5, 6, 7, 8]

const intersection = rootChildren.intersection(predecessors); // [5, 6, 7]

const result = intersection.add(requiredRootNode); // [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use either use [`depthFirstSearch`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.depthFirstSearch) or [`breadthFirstSearch`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.breadthFirstSearch).**

The code sample there would allow you to change the `visit`. Change the following to your liking:

```js
const limitingID = '4';

var bfs = cy.elements().bfs({
    roots: '#e',
    visit: function(v){
        // Stopping at desired node
        if( v.id == limitingID ){
            return true;
        }
    },
    directed: false 
});

var path = bfs.path; // path to found node
var found = bfs.found; // found node
```

Comment: AFAIK, the search algorithms give the shortest path they can find and not all the paths.